# How can I calc sum for jsonb in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have few records with a field "data" that contains a jsonb with cryptocurrencies amounts:

(cryptocurrencies can be different and in any quantity)

[image]

The task is to calculate the total amount of cryptocurrency and get something like:

```
CODE:    SUM:
BTC      185.00002100
DOGE     2.00000000
```

How can I do this with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_each_text` in a `CROSS JOIN` to extract each element of your json records, after that sum the `values` grouping by `key`

```
SELECT j.key, sum(j.value::numeric)
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN jsonb_each_text(data::jsonb) j (key,value)
GROUP BY j.key
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d30c2c5251e2c27187a8ad726d30321)

Answer (score 1):

A natural approach is to get the sums in a single row:

```sql
with my_table(data) as (
values
    ('{"BTC": "0.1"}'::jsonb),
    ('{"BTC": "0.2", "DOGE": "2.0"}'),
    ('{"BTC": "0.3"}')
)

select 
    sum((data->>'BTC')::numeric) as btc, 
    sum((data->>'DOGE')::numeric) as doge
from my_table;

 btc | doge
-----+------
 0.6 |  2.0
(1 row)
```

If you insist on a columnar presentation:

```sql
with my_table(data) as (
values
    ('{"BTC": "0.1"}'::jsonb),
    ('{"BTC": "0.2", "DOGE": "2.0"}'),
    ('{"BTC": "0.3"}')
)

select code, sum((data->>code)::numeric)
from my_table
cross join unnest(array['BTC', 'DOGE']) as code
group by code
order by code;

 code | sum
------+-----
 BTC  | 0.6
 DOGE | 2.0
(2 rows)
```